# file /etc/php.ini from install of php-common-5.1.6-39.el5_8.i386 conflicts with file from package php53u-common-5.3.19-1.ius.el5.i386

Tags: mysqli, centos, rpm

when I install mysqli on my centos

```
# yum -y install php-mysqli
```

he tell me that:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /etc/php.ini from install of php-common-5.1.6-39.el5_8.i386 conflicts with file from package php53u-common-5.3.19-1.ius.el5.i386
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: This question is better suited to http://serverfault.com/ or http://superuser.com/ since it doesn't have anything to do with programming.

Answer (score 0):

As the output says:

php-common-5.1.6-39.el5_8.i386 (a dependency of php-mysqli)
conflicts with php53u-common-5.3.19-1.ius.el5.i386

Just remove php53u-common-5.3.19-1.ius.el5.i386 if you want php-mysqli.